# Why is this happening? I'm getting correct display in console output and right amount of rows in UI but I'm getting no outputs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

```
<template>
    <div v-if = "currentUser" class="edit-form">
        <h4>User</h4>
            <form>
                <div class = "form-group">
                    <label for = "name">Name</label>
                    <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "name"
                    v-model = "currentUser.Ime"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class = "form-group">
                    <label for = "lastName">Last name</label>
                    <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "lastName"
                    v-model = "currentUser.Prezime" 
                    />
                </div>
                <div class = "form-group">
                    <label for = "address">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class = "form-control" id="address"
                        v-model = "currentUser.Adresa"
                    />
                </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h4>Phone Numbers</h4>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"
                        v-for="number in numbers" :key="number"
                        >   
                        {{ number.Broj }}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>

            </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import userServices from "../services/userServices.js";
    export default {
        name: "user",
        data() {
            return {
                numbers: [],
                currentUser: null,
                number: "",
                Broj: ""
            };
        },

        methods: {
            getUser(id) {
                userServices.get(id)
                .then(response => {
                    this.currentUser = response.data;
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e);
                });
            },
            retrieveNumbers(id) {
                userServices.getNumber(id).then(response => {
                    this.numbers = response.data;
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e);
                });
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.getUser(this.$route.params.id);
            this.retrieveNumbers(this.$route.params.id);
        }
    };
</script>

<style>
    .edit-form {
        max.width: 300px;
        margin: auto;
    }
</style>
```

So I have this problem with displaying phone numbers for user. Console output is displaying numbers, and my user interface is displaying the right amount of rows but not numbers themselves.

I'm trying to find the mistake I made in my code, but I got stuck.

Please help. Thank you. And please, no no-answers :)

[image: so here is what im getting now]

Comment: Can you share a sample data that you want to display?

Comment: I've edited my question with screen shot what I'm getting now. So in this table should be phone numbers. It show right amount of rows and CLI is displaying the numbers, but my UI is not.

Comment: Why you are writing `number.Broj`?

Comment: Isn't that a reference to a table in database? for example name.Name etc :D Broj means number :)

Comment: Try just using `number` in the field instead of `number.Broj`.

Comment: okay I'm getting numbers. But in format like this { "Number": "016223223" }

Comment: Use `number.Number`

Answer (score 0):

try to use async await for your calls.
also be sure that ur `id` for `retrieveNumbers(id)` is set correct and the api is responding with a payload.

```js
<script>
    import userServices from "../services/userServices.js";
    export default {
        name: "user",
        data() {
            return {
                numbers: [],
                currentUser: null,
                number: "",
                Broj: ""
            };
        },

        methods: {
            async getUser(id) {
                await userServices.get(id)
                .then(response => {
                    this.currentUser = response.data;
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e);
                });
            },
            async retrieveNumbers(id) {
                await userServices.getNumber(id).then(response => {
                    this.numbers = response.data;
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e);
                });
            }
        },
        async created() {
           await this.getUser(this.$route.params.id);
            await this.retrieveNumbers(this.$route.params.id);
        }
    };
</script>
```